# How to change Wordpress' default posts permalinks programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

In the backend of Wordpress I use the default `http://localhost/sitename/example-post/` value for creating permalinks.

For custom post types I defined a custom slug this way, here is `services` for example:

```
register_post_type( 'service',
    array(
        'labels'      => array(
            'name'          => __( 'Services' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Service' )
        ),
        'public'      => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite'     => array(
            'slug'       => 'services',
            'with_front' => true
        ),
        'supports'    => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail'
        ),
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' ),
    )
);
```

It creates **services/post-name**.

I also use this hook to create a custom page to create a custom page permalink:

```
function custom_base_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . '/page/%pagename%/';
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_base_rules' );
```

It creates **page/post-name**

Now the only thing I need to do is to create another custom permalink path for the normal Wordpress **posts**.

So the outcome world be for the post type of `post`:

**post/post-name**

I can't use the backed for this because I already defined a default way of handling the permalinks. I already managed to rewrite the paths of custom post types and pages...

How do I rewrite the normal `post` post type permalink path in Wordpress programmatically?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `permalink_structure` property suggested by GentlemanMax did not work for me. But I found a method that does work, set_permalink_structure(). See code example below.

```
function custom_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . '/page/%pagename%/'; // custom page permalinks
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( $wp_rewrite->root . '/post/%postname%/' ); // custom post permalinks
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_permalinks' );
```

Comment: This does exactly the samething as setting up the permalinks in the admin dashboard though... It prepends `/post/` to categories, and everything as well.

Comment: This function sets a page path and a different post path. Setting it up in the backend allows you to only use one path.

Comment: Yeah, this messes up the custom post type links. Figured out an another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58099816/153718

Comment: In my case this was the solution Elepi. Maybe you have to visit the permalink page to refresh them?

Comment: affirmative, Eselpi's solution also worked for me, but I had to visit the permalink page to refresh them.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do it in two steps.

First enable rewrite with `'with_front' => true` for the buildin post registration

```php
add_filter(
    'register_post_type_args',
    function ($args, $post_type) {
        if ($post_type !== 'post') {
            return $args;
        }

        $args['rewrite'] = [
            'slug' => 'posts',
            'with_front' => true,
        ];

        return $args;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

This way urls like `http://foo.example/posts/a-title` work but generated links in are now wrong.

Links can be fixed by forcing custom permalink structure for the buildin posts

```php
add_filter(
    'pre_post_link',
    function ($permalink, $post) {
        if ($post->post_type !== 'post') {
            return $permalink;
        }

        return '/posts/%postname%/';
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d46f9b4fb8fdf64e02a4a995c0c2ce9f014b9cb7/wp-includes/link-template.php#L166

Comment: Should note that with this approach your canonical URLs are going to be off since WP still thinks your posts exist at the root.

Answer (score 0):

Posts have to use the default permalink structure, they do not have a special entry in the rewrite object in the same way that pages or custom post types do.  If you want to change the default structure programmatically, you can add something like this to your hook.

```
$wp_rewrite->permalink_structure = '/post/%postname%';
```

I'm not super clear what you mean when you say

> I can't use the backed for this because I already defined a default way of handling the permalinks. I already managed to rewrite the paths of custom post types and pages...

It sounds as though you're overriding the default behavior for permalinks everywhere except for posts so if you changed the default it would likely only affect posts anyway.

Comment: If I change the default setting for the permalink structure it also effects the custom post type permalinks from what I can remember. But that's not what I want, I want to use custom paths for both.